# Resize webpage to 1024 by 768

Tags: html

I have a webpage application.

I wish to customize my pages to suit the resolution 1024 by 768.

Currently, when i change my display resolution, my tables are affected in the display browser using firefox. Please assist.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to hardwire a resolution as you are trying to do. It's generally not a good idea to take away the power of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've written the page yourself, you would be quickly able to identify places which you set as fixed width/height. make a note of all those. Then figure out the ones that you want to tie to the screen resolution. Use the percentage unit for specifying the width height like so:

```
table {
  width : 90% //instead of say 700px
}
```

With percentages, the table will automatically expand contract when window resizes. Have a look at the min-width/height properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the page styling. Usually the web page style is put in a separate CSS file and that particular CSS file is loaded and used by the web browser to display the page. So, if you look into your CSS file you can change its style.
You can also use the firefox add-on called "firebug" to identify the exact elements that you like to modify in your CSS file.

For a quick CSS tutorial you may check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).